# Fixed sticky header

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have some task, I need to have one header in the home page and different headers in all other pages!

I wrote a script when is page no home: do some changes with JQuery. All is good now, but I have one point, the wrapper of main menu and language settings sometimes move when I'm scroling page down.

I can't fix it.

Here is my website http://dita.q44.nl/ (home page) and
http://dita.q44.nl/register/ (other page, which need fix).

Thanks you all, if you help me...

Comment: @djl when you are editing the question, cant you change the grammer too so op's line will make sense? please edit for better understanding of the question. thanx

Answer (score 0):

The issue is on your internal pages (not home page) you add a `.sticky` to your `.site-header` and this cause changes in the header height from `71px` to `91px`.

the solution is you don't have to toggle `.sticky` class on scroll you just need to add leave it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Well i think the problem is here when i do disable it everything is fine

```
   @media only screen and (min-width: 63.9375em)
.site-header .main-navigation, .site-header .site-tools {
    /* height: 66px; */
    /* line-height: 59px; */
}
```

when you scroll it down it increasing your height to 66px

Try this 
it will work only on your home page

```
.home .top-headers-wrapper.on_page_scroll {
        background: #fff;
    }
```

Comment: are you using any theme?

Comment: `@media only screen and (min-width: 63.9375em)
.site-header .main-navigation, .site-header .site-tools {
    height: 46px;
    line-height: 0 !important;
}`

Comment: i think it is coming from theme option please check there if you find any or paste the code i write above, on theme option's custom css field

Comment: all is good now, but i have problem with home page, it is no white background, when i school down page.

Comment: This is will make your nav background white

`.home .top-headers-wrapper.on_page_scroll {
    background: #fff;
}`